# Deborphan false positive: libmagickwand-dev:all

Tags: apt, package-management

On `Pop!_OS 20.10` (system76's ubuntu variant), after `apt install libmagickwand-dev`, `deborphan` prints `libmagickwand-dev:all`.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t a bug, but you aren’t doing anything *wrong*. `libmagickwand-dev` is marked as a transitional package, pulling in `libmagickwand-6.q16-dev`. It’s in the `oldlibs` section, which is why `deborphan` considers it, and since it’s a leaf package it ends up listed as an orphan.

You could install `libmagickwand-6.q16-dev` directly to avoid this.

In more detail, `libmagickwand-dev` can be identified as a transitional package because it’s in the `oldlibs` section, and because its package description says “This is a transitional package to help migrate systems to the new ABI of libmagickwand-6 development files for default channel depth.” (These are [documented best practices for transitional packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.en.html#make-transition-packages-deborphan-compliant).)

To list transitional packages installed on your system, try the following:

- `dpkg -l | grep -E 'transitional|dummy'`
- `deborphan --guess-dummy`
- `aptitude search '~soldlibs ~i'`

The purpose of a transitional package is to allow transitions: if package A is supposed to be replaced by package B, we can’t just drop A in favour of B; we first need to ship A and B, then wait for all the packages depending on A to be updated to B, then drop A. While the transition is in progress, new users of A or B should install B directly.